# Excel file keeps opening even Application.On Time schedule is off

Tags: excel, vba, schedule

I hope someone can help me about problem that i have.
I created workbook than will on opening start few macros:

Refresh_time - runs every second to update time counter

Save_it - saves file on every 30 minutes

Order - runs marco Save_order at specific time, 02, 10 and 18 hours

Also there is few marcos which will close file if there is no activity for 10 minutes.

In both cases, if file is closed due to inactivity or closed manualy, it keeps opening by it self.

Do anybody have idea where i have made mistake?

In ThisWorkbook

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Refresh_time
    Save_it
    Order
    TimeSetting

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    
    Stop_
    TimeStop
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
 
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

   TimeStop
   TimeSetting

End Sub
```

In Module1

```
Public dTimeB, dTimeS, dTimeT1, dTimeT2, dTimeT3, CloseTime As Date


Sub Stop_()


    Application.OnTime dTimeB, "Refresh_time", , False
    Application.OnTime dTimeS, "Save_it", , False
    Application.OnTime dTimeT1, "Save_order", , False
    Application.OnTime dTimeT2, "Save_order", , False
    Application.OnTime dTimeT3, "Save_order", , False
    
End Sub

Sub TimeSetting()


    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=CloseTime, Procedure:="SavedAndClose", Schedule:=False
    On Error GoTo 0
    CloseTime = Now() + TimeValue("00:03:00")
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=CloseTime, Procedure:="SavedAndClose", Schedule:=True

End Sub
Sub TimeStop()

    On Error Resume Next

    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=CloseTime, _
      Procedure:="SavedAndClose", Schedule:=False

 End Sub
Sub SavedAndClose()

    ActiveWorkbook.Close Savechanges:=True

End Sub

Sub Refresh_time()

    Dim Smena_1, Smena_2, Smena_3 As Date
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=dTimeB, Procedure:="Refresh_time", Schedule:=False
    On Error GoTo 0
    dTimeB = Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=dTimeB, Procedure:="Refresh_time", Schedule:=True
    
    Smena_1 = Date + TimeValue("10:00:00")
    Smena_2 = Date + TimeValue("18:00:00")
    Smena_3 = Date + 1 + TimeValue("02:00:00")
    vreme = Date + Time
    
    If vreme < Smena_1 Then
        Y = Smena_1 - vreme
        Else
        If vreme < Smena_2 Then
            Y = Smena_2 - vreme
            Else
                Y = Smena_3 - vreme
    
        End If
    End If
        Workbooks("Lager MES REO zica_MM.xlsm").Worksheets("Pocetna").Vreme_porucivanja.Value = Format(Y, "hh:mm:ss")
    
        Workbooks("Lager MES REO zica_MM.xlsm").Worksheets("Pocetna").Za_porucivanje.Value = Application.CountA(Workbooks("Lager MES REO zica_MM.xlsm").Worksheets("Za porucivanje").Range("A:A")) - 1

End Sub

Sub Save_it()

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=dTimeS, Procedure:="Save_it", Schedule:=False
    On Error GoTo 0
    dTimeS = Now() + TimeValue("00:10:00")
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=dTimeS, Procedure:="Save_it", Schedule:=True

End Sub

Sub Order()

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=dTimeT1, Procedure:="Save_order", Schedule:=False
    On Error GoTo 0
    dTimeT1 = TimeValue("02:00:00")
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=dTimeT1, Procedure:="Save_order", Schedule:=True

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=dTimeT2, Procedure:="Save_order", Schedule:=False
    On Error GoTo 0
    dTimeT2 = TimeValue("10:00:00")
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=dTimeT2, Procedure:="Save_order", Schedule:=True

    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=dTimeT3, Procedure:="Save_order", Schedule:=False
    On Error GoTo 0
    dTimeT3 = TimeValue("18:00:00")
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=dTimeT3, Procedure:="Save_order", Schedule:=True

End Sub
```

I did as you suggested, but still is not ok (code is updated). Also, when Order macro run, lets say at 10:00, it runs 3 times. Can you help me with this little more?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing most things correct with application.ontime. But there is one thing you should add. Before setting a new ontime delete the previous.
As an example:

```
dTimeT1 = now() + TimeValue("00:10:00")
Application.OnTime dTimeT1, "Save_order"
```

I would change that too:

```
on error resume next ' in case dTimeT1 is not set
Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=dTimeT1, Procedure:="Save_order", Schedule:=False
on error goto 0
dTimeT1 = now() + TimeValue("00:10:00")
Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=dTimeT1, Procedure:="Save_order", Schedule:=True
```

Because if dTimeT1 is a time in the future you could end up with two application.ontimes set but you can't remove the previous because your variable has been changed.
So always clear the previous one then set a new. This issue occurs when you run the macro manually.

Specific to your question:
I'm not sure about your stop function. Why do you first set a schedule then remove it?

Why not just?

```
Sub Stop_()
    on error resume next
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=dTimeB, Procedure:="Refresh_time", Schedule:=False
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=dTimeS, Procedure:="Save_it", Schedule:=False
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=dTimeT1, Procedure:="Save_order", Schedule:=False
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=dTimeT2, Procedure:="Save_order", Schedule:=False
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=dTimeT3, Procedure:="Save_order", Schedule:=False
    on error goto 0 
End Sub
```

As an example of how this is an issue:

```
' set this to some time in future
dTimeT1 = TimeValue("12:00:00") 
Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=dTimeT1, Procedure:="Save_order", Schedule:=True

' we now set a new time
dTimeT1 = TimeValue("12:05:00")
Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=dTimeT1, Procedure:="Save_order", Schedule:=True

' we simulate a close of the workbook which should remove the schedule
Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=dTimeT1, Procedure:="Save_order", Schedule:=false
```

But this code will run at 12:00 anyways because you set two schedules but only removes one.